# How to render remote and local video in different view in webrtc android

Tags: android, webrtc

I'm using a single GLSurfaceView for rendering both local and remote video.
So could not customize the local video view. I need to render local and remote video in separate GLSurface.

Now I'm using below GLSurfaceView for both local and remote video rendering.

```
<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/glview_call"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

I need to display local view in `@+id/local_video` and remote view  in `@+id/remote_video` separately.

```
<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/local_video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/remote_video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

Comment: i am also need for that , pls give me solution if you have got it

Comment: Hello. Have you found the solution yet?

Comment: @TOP see the answer

Answer (score 0):

Webrtc team updated their project.Clone the newest code. They have maintain each view(Remote and Local)separately. Check the latest ApprtcDemo code.

Comment: can you tell me what is the library version you are using.

Comment: Now I'm using version 62

Comment: @Ayyappan is that possible that the newest version for now is 1.0 and the name is changed to `google-webrtc` ?

Comment: @shurrok Actually version will be released when every time chrome updated. please check the link. https://webrtc.org/release-notes/